# Displayed content before the template while reading meta description

Tags: php, meta-tags

This is my code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bancuri WHERE id = '$bancid'") or die(mysql_error());

while ($coloana = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $nume = $coloana["nume"];
    $banc = $coloana["banc"];
    $oras = $coloana["oras"];
    $categorie = $coloana["categorie"];
    $id = $coloana["id"];
    $keywords = $coloana["keywords"];
}
```

I have set the meta description to read the field `$banc`.

The problem is that, on a few pages, it shows me the content of `$banc` before the templates begins.

I don't know why; it should be visible only for search engine robots.

The meta tag is written like this `<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="<?php echo $banc; ?>" />`

What is causing this problem?

Comment: This can't be answered without seeing the contents of `$banc`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a / are some double quotes in the `$banc` variable.

Comment: looking into db , and testing the url of some `$banc` where id result, seams to double quotes only where it's starts with some HTML code like `<p>` or `<b>` or contain any HTML code.

Comment: seams that `<br />` tag is ignored

Comment: look this one contains `<br>` -> `http://dirlink.ro/beta/banc.php?banc_id=3` and this too `http://dirlink.ro/beta/banc.php?banc_id=338` almous the same caracters numbers.